# Extend Spring MVC class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to extend a Spring MVC class which is the [`ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.html) and override the [`getMaximumSessionsForThisUser`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.html#getMaximumSessionsForThisUser-org.springframework.security.core.Authentication-) method with my own implementation.

How do I register or communicate to Spring to use my implementation of it's method rather than it's own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For XML configuration, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#sessionauthenticationstrategy):

> **21.2 SessionAuthenticationStrategy**
>
> `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` is used by both `SessionManagementFilter` and `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, so if you are using a customized form-login class, for example, you will need to inject it into both of these. In this case, a typical configuration, combining the namespace and custom beans might look like this:
>
> ```xml
> <http>
>      <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter" />
>      <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>
> </http>
>
> <beans:bean id="myAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
> <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
>     ...
> </beans:bean>
>
> <beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy" />
> ```

For Java configuration, see [`SessionManagementConfigurer#sessionAuthenticationStrategy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/SessionManagementConfigurer.html#sessionAuthenticationStrategy-org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy-):

> ```
> public SessionManagementConfigurer<H> sessionAuthenticationStrategy(SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy)
> ```
>
> Allows explicitly specifying the `SessionAuthenticationStrategy`. The default is to use `SessionFixationProtectionStrategy`. If restricting the maximum number of sessions is configured, then `CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy` delegating to `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy`, `SessionFixationProtectionStrategy` (the default) OR `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` the supplied sessionAuthenticationStrategy, `RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy`. NOTE: Supplying a custom `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` will override the default provided `SessionFixationProtectionStrategy`.

Comment: So that means I will have to refer the session management in spring security to use my own session authentication strategy which will be my XYZ class which extends ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.